# Hide sheet if cell on anther sheet meets conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write a macro that will hide a sheet once the reference cell on a "Home" sheet is highlighted Green.

Attempted If Statement:

```
Dim Archive As String
Archive = ActiveSheet.Name
If Sheets("Home").Range("$A:$1).Value = Archive And Sheets("Home") _
    .Range("$A:$1).Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
ActiveSheet.Hide
End If
```

The sheet and cell I am attempting to reference have the same name. The cell is Hyperlinked to the sheet. Both the Sheet and the cell with hyperlink are created by another macro.

I cannot identify a specific cell in the If statement because the cell will be different depending on the sheet I want to hide.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's a good idea to check for existing solutions to your questions.  A couples examples are [**here**](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3561-excel-hide-sheet-based-on-cell-value.html) and [**here**](https://excel.tips.net/T001940_Hiding_Rows_Based_on_a_Cell_Value.html) and [**here**](https://superuser.com/a/1138864/774713). Also, check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as "[ask]" and this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user.

Comment: you are not closing the `Range` string with `"`, just change `.Range("$A:$1).Value` to `.Range("A1").Value` (you don't need the `$` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you out,

You can create a module and paste the following method over there.

```
Sub checkRef(ByVal shtName As String)
Dim archive As String
archive = shtName
If Sheets("Home").Range("A1").Value = archive And Sheets("Home").Range("A1").Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
    ActiveSheet.Visible = False
Else
    MsgBox "Activesheet not referenced to hide"
End If
End Sub
```

You can edit the above as per your need.

Then on the **Worksheet_Activate** event of the worksheet you want to hide call the above method as given below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
checkRef (ActiveSheet.Name)
End Sub
```

Then you can check the result by changing the value of Range("A1") of **Home** sheet to Name of the sheet you want to hide and also change the interior color to **vbGreen**.

You must be able to hide your sheet.